# emscripten not generating .html file with MODULARIZE and EXPORT_NAME parameters set

Tags: emscripten

In emscripten if I compile using `-s MODULARIZE=1` I have to also include `-s EXPORT_NAME=AnotherModuleName`, e.g.

```
emcc my_code.cpp -O1 -std=c++14 -pthread -s PTHREAD_POOL_SIZE=4 -s MODULARIZE=1 -s EXPORT_NAME=XModule -o pthreads.html
```

Using the most recent compiler, this gives an error:

> emcc: error: Customizing EXPORT_NAME requires that the HTML be customized to use that name (see https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/10086)

Emscripten generates everything except the `.html` file.

I'm a bit lost as to what to do, but the previous working `.html` file was as below. How can I update this, as the error message suggests, to work with `XModule` ? Simply replacing `Module` with `XModule` doesn't do anything.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Emscripten-Generated Code</title>
        <style>
      body {
        font-family: arial;
        margin: 0;
        padding: none;
      }

      .emscripten { padding-right: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; }
      div.emscripten { text-align: center; }      
      div.emscripten_border { border: 1px solid black; }
      /* the canvas *must not* have any border or padding, or mouse coords will be wrong */
      canvas.emscripten { border: 0px none; background-color: black; }

      #emscripten_logo {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .spinner {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;

        -webkit-animation: rotation .8s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation: rotation .8s linear infinite;
        -o-animation: rotation .8s linear infinite;
        animation: rotation 0.8s linear infinite;

        border-left: 5px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
        border-right: 5px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
        border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
        border-top: 5px solid rgb(120, 120, 120);
        
        border-radius: 100%;
        background-color: rgb(189, 215, 46);
      }

      @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
        from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
        to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
      }
      @-moz-keyframes rotation {
        from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
        to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
      }
      @-o-keyframes rotation {
        from {-o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
        to {-o-transform: rotate(360deg);}
      }
      @keyframes rotation {
        from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
        to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
      }

      #status {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: rgb(120, 120, 120);
      }

      #progress {
        height: 20px;
        width: 300px;
      }

      #controls {
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-right: 20px;
      }

      #output {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        border-left: 0px;
        border-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        display: block;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
        outline: none;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://emscripten.org"></a>

        <div class="spinner" id='spinner'></div>
        <div class="emscripten" id="status">Downloading...</div>

        <span id='controls'>
            <span><input type="checkbox" id="resize">Resize canvas</span>
            <span><input type="checkbox" id="pointerLock" checked>Lock/hide
                mouse pointer &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <span><input type="button" value="Fullscreen"
                    onclick="Module.requestFullscreen(document.getElementById('pointerLock').checked,
                    document.getElementById('resize').checked)">
            </span>
        </span>

        <div class="emscripten">
            <progress value="0" max="100" id="progress" hidden=1></progress>
        </div>


        <div class="emscripten_border">
            <canvas class="emscripten" id="canvas"
                oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" tabindex=-1></canvas>
        </div>
        <textarea id="output" rows="8"></textarea>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
      var statusElement = document.getElementById('status');
      var progressElement = document.getElementById('progress');
      var spinnerElement = document.getElementById('spinner');

      var Module = {
        preRun: [],
        postRun: [],
        print: (function() {
          var element = document.getElementById('output');
          if (element) element.value = ''; // clear browser cache
          return function(text) {
            if (arguments.length > 1) text = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(' ');
            // These replacements are necessary if you render to raw HTML
            //text = text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
            //text = text.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
            //text = text.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
            //text = text.replace('\n', '<br>', 'g');
            console.log(text);
            if (element) {
              element.value += text + "\n";
              element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight; // focus on bottom
            }
          };
        })(),
        canvas: (function() {
          var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

          // As a default initial behavior, pop up an alert when webgl context is lost. To make your
          // application robust, you may want to override this behavior before shipping!
          // See http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.15.2
          canvas.addEventListener("webglcontextlost", function(e) { alert('WebGL context lost. You will need to reload the page.'); e.preventDefault(); }, false);

          return canvas;
        })(),
        setStatus: function(text) {
          if (!Module.setStatus.last) Module.setStatus.last = { time: Date.now(), text: '' };
          if (text === Module.setStatus.last.text) return;
          var m = text.match(/([^(]+)\((\d+(\.\d+)?)\/(\d+)\)/);
          var now = Date.now();
          if (m && now - Module.setStatus.last.time < 30) return; // if this is a progress update, skip it if too soon
          Module.setStatus.last.time = now;
          Module.setStatus.last.text = text;
          if (m) {
            text = m[1];
            progressElement.value = parseInt(m[2])*100;
            progressElement.max = parseInt(m[4])*100;
            progressElement.hidden = false;
            spinnerElement.hidden = false;
          } else {
            progressElement.value = null;
            progressElement.max = null;
            progressElement.hidden = true;
            if (!text) spinnerElement.style.display = 'none';
          }
          statusElement.innerHTML = text;
        },
        totalDependencies: 0,
        monitorRunDependencies: function(left) {
          this.totalDependencies = Math.max(this.totalDependencies, left);
          Module.setStatus(left ? 'Preparing... (' + (this.totalDependencies-left) + '/' + this.totalDependencies + ')' : 'All downloads complete.');
        }
      };
      Module.setStatus('Downloading...');
      window.onerror = function(event) {
        // TODO: do not warn on ok events like simulating an infinite loop or exitStatus
        Module.setStatus('Exception thrown, see JavaScript console');
        spinnerElement.style.display = 'none';
        Module.setStatus = function(text) {
          if (text) console.error('[post-exception status] ' + text);
        };
      };
    </script>
        <script async type="text/javascript" src="pthreads.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```